# When needing to use another thread, should you use Bukkit's implmentation or Java's?

Tags: java, bukkit

I require the need to run a process async but I am unsure if I should use Bukkit's implementation (BukkitRunnable) or Java's. Which is considered to be more standard when developing a Bukkit plugin?

Comment: If they provide a means of running tasks in the main thread, I suspect they expect you to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered to be a standardized approach to use Bukkit's version as that was the reason that they developed it; for this exact purpose.